# Best regex pattern to replace input function from a separate python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am new to regex so please explain how you got to the answer. Anyway I want to know the best way to match input function from a separate python file.

For example:

match.py

```
a = input("Enter a number")
b = input()
print(a+b)
```

Now I want to match ONLY the input statement and replace it with a random number. I will do this in a separate file `main.py`. So my aim is to replace input function in the `match.py` with a random numbers so I can check the output will come as expected. You can think of `match.py` like a coding exercise where he writes the code in that file and `main.py` will be the file where it evaluates if the users code is right. And to do that I need to replace the input myself and check if it works for all kinds of inputs. I looked for "regex patterns for python input function" but the search did not work right. I have a current way of doing it but I don't think it works in all kinds of cases. I need a perfect pattern which works in all kinds of cases referring to the python syntax. Here is the current `main.py` I have (It doesn't work for all cases I mean when you write a string with single quote, it does not replace but here is the problem I can just add single quote in pattern but I also need to detect if both are used):

```
# Evaluating python file checking if input 2 numbers and print sum is correct

import re
import subprocess

input_pattern = re.compile(r"input\s?\([\"]?[\w]*[\"]?\)")
file = open("match.py", 'r')
read = file.read()
file.close()

code = read

matches = input_pattern.findall(code)

for match in matches:
    code = code.replace(match, '8')

file = open("match.py", 'w')
file.write(code)
file.close()

process = subprocess.Popen('python3 match.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

out = process.communicate()[0]
print(out == b"16\n")

file = open("match.py", 'w')
file.write(read)
file.close()
```

Please let me know if you don't understand this question.

Comment: I think this regex pattern will cover most situations that I can think of: `input\(.*\)`

Comment: Well here is the problem what if the user writes code something like this: `input(")`. So in my case I am actually allowing the person who writes the code to make a mistake but he can get away with it.

Comment: Ok - so what do you want to happen in that case when the user writes it incorrectly? Leave it the way it is so that it generates an error ?

Comment: @ScottC exactly. I want it to leave it that way so it generates an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex statement is very close to what you need:

```
input\s?\((?(?=[\"\'])[\"\'].*[\"\']\)|\))
```

I am using a [conditional regex statement](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). However, I think it may need a **nested** conditional to avoid the situation that the user enters something like:
`input(' text ")` 
But hopefully this gets you on the right track.